# Store, change, and update opacity using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new here and new to programming, so apologies in advance if this question is very basic and the answer is already here. I've done a lot of searching, but I've been unable to find the information I need.

What JavaScript code could I use to pull the current opacity value of a div, update that value, and reapply the updated value to that same div? In essence, I'm doing an exercise that involves gradually increasing the opacity of individual divs in a large grid on the mouseover event. Each individual div in the grid should have a 0.1 increase in opacity every time the mouse enters that div, up to the point of having an opacity of 1.

I already know how to do this in jQuery, I'm just trying to expand my knowledge of JavaScript at the moment.

Comment: Anything that jQuery can do can be done in plain Javascript. If you already have working jQuery code for this then perhaps you could [edit]  your question to show it? Then perhaps we could give some tips about how to replace whatever jQuery methods you are using with vanilla JS equivalents.

Comment: Well figure out how to do it for one cell and than apply that to all the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how you'd set opacities and events with jQuery:

```
// `elem` is the element you want to affect

// get opacity
var oldOpacity = $(elem).css('opacity');

// set opacity
$(elem).css('opacity', 0.5);

// add mouseover event
$(elem).on('mouseover', function onMouseOver(e) {
  // do stuff with opacities
});
```

And here's how you'd do the above with vanilla DOM methods:

```
// `elem` is the element you want to affect

// get opacity
var oldOpacity = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('opacity');

// set opacity
elem.style.setPropertyValue('opacity', 0.5);

// add mouseover event
elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function onMouseOver(e) {
  // do stuff with opacities
}, false);
```

To get the element, you can use old DOM methods like `document.getElementById` or the new methods `document.querySelectorAll` and `document.querySelector` which are very much like jQuery in that they take a CSS selector and return a Node or list of Nodes.

To, say, retrieve all of the `li` elements with the class `list-item`, and iterate over them, you would do this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('li.list-item');
var i, l = elems.length, elem;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
  elem = elems[i];
  // do stuff with elem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, still new to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Here's the 'vanilla' JS way to check and update opacity, with the caveat that this only works in browsers; it won't work in NodeJS because there's no document in node. You can try it on this page by opening dev tools (right-click, inspect, console in Chrome).

```
var div = document.querySelector('.post-text')
console.log(div.style.opacity) // ""
div.style.opacity = 0.5
console.log(div.style.opacity) // "0.5"
```

So for your exercise, you'll want to assign the mouseover function like so:

```
function changeOpacity (element, delta) {
  element.style.opacity = Number(element.style.opacity) + Number(delta)
}
var element = document.querySelector('.post-text')
var opacityDelta = -0.1
document.onmouseover = function () { changeOpacity(element, opacityDelta) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with these lines of code.

with vanilla Js.

I commented too.

```js
// Vanilla Js.

//Getting elements.

var box = document.querySelector('.box');

var refresh = document.querySelector('.refresh');

// Assigning opacity

var defaultOpacity = 0.2;

box.style.opacity = defaultOpacity;


// Events.

// Opacity adding event on hover

box.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  var oldOp = e.target.style.opacity;

   oldOp = Number.parseFloat(oldOp);
  
  oldOp += defaultOpacity;
  
  e.target.style.opacity = oldOp;
  
}, false);

//Refresh Evet.

refresh.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  box.style.opacity = defaultOpacity;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      background: #48A64C;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="box"></div>
    
    <p> Yeah you can refresh too </p>

    <button class = "refresh">refresh</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!